# Soupsieve package not installed | automate the boring stuff

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working through the web scraping portion of 'Automate the Boring Stuff' and am getting the following error when trying to use `BeautifulSoup`

```
UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.
```

I have run `pip install beautifulsoup4` and `pip install soupsieve`. The line that is causing the error is:

```
comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
```

I have looked around and haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests, os, bs4

url = 'http://xkcd.com'
os.makedirs('xkcd')
while not url.endswith('#'):
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")
comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
if comicElem == []:
    print('Could not find the comic image.')
else:
    comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')
#Download the image
    print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
    res = requests.get(comicUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Could you give the code that outputs the error?

Comment: Which version of soupsieve have you installed?

Comment: If Soup Sieve is failing to import, this could happen. If you try `import soupsieve` do you get an error?

Comment: @Xilpex `comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')`

Comment: Ok. Thanks... :D

Comment: @Xilpex added code above

Comment: @skaul05 Version is 1.8

Comment: @facelessuser When I import soupsieve I get the following error `ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cach`

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: `pip install backports.functools_lru_cache` That should get you the missing requirement. Python 2.7 needs this dependency while Python 3 does not as it has `lru_cache` built in. I'm uncertain why `pip install soupsieve` didn't install this requirement for you though.

Comment: Maybe you need to `pip install -U pip` and `pip install -U setuptools` so that it properly installs these kinds of requirements for you in the future.

Comment: @facelessuser I got it to work by uninstalling/reinstalling `backports.functools_lru_cache`. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working.